# How to resolve class name clashing in Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON libs in my Swift-based iOS app, and the problem is they both have a "JSON" class, which of course doesn't work. How to solve this? Is it possible to use namespaces, or something similar? Would compile these classes into separate frameworks, and then refer the frameworks instead of adding the source code classes, work?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you have to do:

- Download the latest version of both libraries from [GitHub](http://github.com).
- Add them to your project.
- Add the resulting frameworks as dependencies for your app.
- Add `import <insert_json_lib_module_name_here>` to the appropriate classes.
- Change all references to the library classes from `<insert_json_lib_class_name_here>` to `<insert_json_lib_module_name_here>.<insert_json_lib_class_name_here>`

And that's it. It's all documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1089).

Comment: cool...however there's no way to work around that unless the libraries are compiled into separate frameworks right? If I just add their source code to the main project I cannot specify a namespace for the classes, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes compile the JSON lib classes into separate framework.